# Can i achieve dynamic routing in nextJS for nested routes with unknown number of slugs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, next.js

In nextJS routing is path based for pages but is there anyway to achieve a common route for following:

```
http://localhost/abc/element/id
http://localhost/abc/def/element/id
http://localhost/abc/def/ghi/element/id
```

> Note how /element/id is common in all

I understand i can make nested folder structure and redirect them to same component but i want to avoid the same as we can further more nesting.

Do take care that you can not use catch all as it should be at the end just before file extension.
Also, i don't want to add an extra prefix to the URL as that makes the older url's invalid.

Comment: Could you clarify why a catch-all route wouldn't be sufficient here?

Comment: For catch all route it will catch routes such as /abc/def/element2/anything
it will catch basic of routes also.@catgirlkelly

Comment: Yes, but inside the catch-all route you can handle the route if it matches or not. For example, if `/abc/def/element2/anything` triggers the route then you can check if it ends with `/element/id` and if it doesn't, do something else (redirect or render different component). I don't see why you can't use a catch-all here.

Comment: But in case of 10-15 routes and bigger scenario the solution suggested by you is not feasible and looks not arranged it will be a way too many conditionals. @catgirlkelly.
Also it will make the project centralised to the base route.
Also imagine about the unnecessary chunks.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're getting at. It's as simple as an if statement to check if the route ends with `/element/id`?

Comment: But our routes can end in /element2/diffId, /element3/diffId, /element4/diffId.
If i render based on conditionals a lot of unused bundles will be fetched and makes it very complicated application design.

Comment: ... And having this sort of routing system *isn't*? Why do you need this kind of routing? Is it really needed here because it adds more overhead?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244346/discussion-between-imshashi17-and-catgirlkelly).

Comment: Its needed as URLS over web should not change once created. And this route was created long ago.
New URLs will erase older urls that have been shared overtime.